# How to copy files from a directory to iphone document directory

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite

What I am trying to do is, in app delegate, I want to write a code that will copy a sqlite database if it is not exists in iphone's document directory. For that I am using the following code-

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()
window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

//Create database if not exists
let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let databaseStr = "LocalDatabase.sqlite"
let dbPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr)
let fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {
    let databaseInApp: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr)
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(databaseInApp!, toPath: dbPath, error: nil)
}

return true
}
```

It's creating the database in the directory that is ok. But I am not getting ant tables there in database. That means new file is created instead of copying. I am sure there are 9 tables in that database which I want to copy.

Structure of files are as given in the screenshot-

[image]

Where I am wrong that I did not understand. Please tell me if anybody is able to catch the problem. One more thing When I was running the application in the simulator with the 
`/Users/Adelantelabs/Documents/Sidemenu.swift/SlideOutNavigation/Localdatabase.sqlite`
Then it was working perfectly but did not work in iphone when I run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var error : NSError?
var doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("LocalDatabase1.sqlite")
let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LocalDatabase", ofType: "sqlite")
fileManager.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath, error: &error)
```

Comment: Thanks for help in the code. I used the code and was getting nil in the url when I was using `pathForResource` function. For this problem I dragged my file under `Copy Bundle Resources` and it worked..

Answer (score 2):

```
   func copyDatabase(){

            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let dbPath = getDBPath()
        var success = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath)


        if(!success) {
          if let defaultDBPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LocalDatabase", ofType: "sqlite"){

          var error:NSError?
          success = fileManager.copyItemAtPath(defaultDBPath, toPath: dbPath, error: &error)
          println(defaultDBPath)
          if (!success){
          println("Failed to create writable database file with message\(error!.localizedDescription))")
          }
          }else{
            println("Cannot Find File In NSBundle")
          }
        }else{
          println("File Already Exist At:\(dbPath)")
        }
      }


      func getDBPath()->String
      {

      let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
      let documentsDir = paths[0] as! String
      let databasePath = documentsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("LocalDatabase.sqlite")
      return databasePath;
      }
```

Then call it in `didFinishLaunching`:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

     copyDatabase()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help in the code. I used the code and was getting nil in the url when I was using `pathForResource` function. For this problem I dragged my file under `Copy Bundle Resources` and it worked..

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 version**

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
var doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let destinationPath = doumentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("LocalDatabase.sqlite")
let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LocalDatabase", ofType: "sqlite")
do{
  try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath)
}catch let error as NSError {
  print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
}
```