# Could I copy a .db file to the root directory of my project, then insert or delete the data of it?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I know we can not put the plist or other cache file in the root directory of our project.

But if is `.db` file, is it could put in the root directory of our project, let us insert or delete `table` in the `db` file ?

Because I see a demo it is puts in the root directory, it works fine, but I use this in my project, can not insert data to it.

This method I invoke it returns `4`, sometime is `2`:

```
// Private method which handles the actual execution of an SQL statement
private func execute(stmt:OpaquePointer, sql:String)->CInt {
    // Step
    var result = sqlite3_step(stmt)
    if result != SQLITE_OK && result != SQLITE_DONE {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        if let error = String(validatingUTF8:sqlite3_errmsg(self.db)) {
            let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to execute SQL: \(sql), Error: \(error)"
            NSLog(msg)
        }
        return 0
    }
    // Is this an insert
    let upp = sql.uppercased()
    if upp.hasPrefix("INSERT ") {
        // Known limitations: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html
        let rid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(self.db)
        result = CInt(rid)
    } else if upp.hasPrefix("DELETE") || upp.hasPrefix("UPDATE") {
        var cnt = sqlite3_changes(self.db)
        if cnt == 0 {
            cnt += 1
        }
        result = CInt(cnt)
    } else {
        result = 1
    }
    // Finalize
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
    return result
}
```

But I use `SQLPro for SQLite` tool to see the table (which I create by this tool)， the table did not insert any records.

[image]

So, if we can put the `db` file in the root directory, let us to insert or delete data in the `db` file ?

Comment: Project directory is readonly, you need to copy this item to doc dir, then do the operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert, update or delete rows (thus modify your db file) only if it is located in Document directory

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175272/1622430) to discover how to move your .db file at app launch

Comment: so, how can I put the db file in to my document directory?

Comment: Simply add in your
_func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {_
that piece of code